# the base URL to use on the local computer

Tags: php, html, url, radix

(xampp), the How do I use on the local computer. folder layout,

http://www.resimagaci.com/img/90rvnrf.png

ust.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
```

alt.php

```
</body>
</html>
```

sabitler.php

```
<?php
#sabitler
define('BASE_URL', 'base-url');
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include 'kutuphane/sabitler.php';
?>
<?php
$ust= BASE_URL . '/kutuphane/ust.php';
$alt= BASE_URL . '/kutuphane/alt.php';
?>
<?php
include ($ust);
?>
<?php
include ($alt);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `base-url` as the value?

Comment: What are your solutions? 
What would you recommend in the image in the folder structure? 
unfortunately I can not speak English, 
I am writing to translate.